# Debugging System.Web.UI.UserControl only hitting breakpoints once

Tags: .net, cookies, dynamic, user-controls

Hello I have an issue with debugging code of my UserControls. I am adding my UserControls dynamic to a placeHolder on a layout. After the controls have been added to the placeholder, when I have attached VS2008 to my worker process I only get to debug my code once. Normally when i refresh my page in IE / Firefox my breakpoint are hit again, but now they are not. 
This is some of the code used to add controls to my page:

ascx for the UserControl in which the cs adds the other UserControls dynamicly:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptListRenderer" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

part of .cs of this file where I add the controls:

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                Item dataItem = (Item)e.Item.DataItem;

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder content = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("content");
                if (content != null)
                {
                    RenderingReference[] renderings = dataItem.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, false);
                    foreach (RenderingReference rendering in renderings)
                    {
                        string strDataSource = dataItem.ID.ToString();
                        rendering.Settings.DataSource = strDataSource;
                        content.Controls.Add(rendering.RenderingItem.GetControl(rendering.Settings));
                    }
                }
            }
```

What I have also noticed is that when I work with cookies or with dynamicly added controls inside the UserControls that are added dynamicly, I have to rebuild to see effect.
For example:

I add a cookie with a GUID of an item which is used to determine a class on a HyperLink on a dynamicly added control. The class is only changing after a build, while I want it to change after a page refresh without building my project.
Is there anyone around that had similar problems or might have a clue what can be happening here? If I need to be more specific on one of the above described things please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this issue several times now. We are developing on the CMS Sitecore and Sitecore has caching options. When Caching - Vary by data is true on a Rendering that places Controls code behind, those Controls won't be reloaded but re-used. This is why the breakpoints won't be hitted.